# Rounded frame renders differently for each platform

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I'm starting to create apps with `MAUI` because I used to work with Xamarin and I loved it. Now, I have a simple `ListView` where I want to display a model that contains a name, description and flags for a dictionary. In the `ListView.ItemTemplate` I have a `DataTemplate` and a `ViewCell`.

```
<ListView x:Name="listDictionaries" ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionaries}"
          SelectionMode="Single" HasUnevenRows="True" 
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10" 
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Frame BorderColor="White"
                        CornerRadius="50"
                        HeightRequest="50"
                        WidthRequest="50"
                        IsClippedToBounds="True"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="uk.png"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            WidthRequest="50" />
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame BorderColor="White"
                        CornerRadius="30"
                        HeightRequest="30"
                        WidthRequest="30"
                        IsClippedToBounds="True"
                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        TranslationX="-15"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <Image Source="it.png"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HeightRequest="30"
                            WidthRequest="30" />
                    </Frame>

                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                    FontSize="18"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

My idea is to display a big flag SVG image in a round frame and another flag SVG image smaller on the bottom right of the main image. For that, I use `TranslationX`.

The render of the page in Android is what I expect (in the middle in the screenshot below), iOS is closed and Windows is completely wrong.

Is it possible to obtain the same render for every platform?

Comment: [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame) is deprecated in MAUI

Comment: Ah, because I found this code on the Microsoft documentation updated recently. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame#round-elements

Comment: That is the same page I linked to.  There is a large warning box on the page that explains `Frame` is included for ease of migration and is not recommended for new development

Comment: It is not working for iOS

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason), the problem was that `Frame` is deprecated in `MAUI`.

So, with the following code, the render is correct for Windows and Android but not for iOS. In order to fix iOS, you have to wrap the image in a grid.

```
<Border HeightRequest="50"
        WidthRequest="50"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50"
        Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="uk.png"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                HeightRequest="50"
                WidthRequest="50" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
<Border HeightRequest="30"
        WidthRequest="30"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        VerticalOptions="End"
        TranslationX="-15"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 30"
        Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="it.png"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                HeightRequest="30"
                WidthRequest="30" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

### Workaround for iOS

To fix the issue with iOS, the `Image` has to be wrapped in a `Grid`.

[image]

Comment: Glad to see that you've solved it and thanks to Jason. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.